Is it necessary for $g'$ to be continuous?
Consider the initial value problem
$$u_t + b \cdot Du = 0 \quad \text{in}\,\,R^n \times(0, \infty),$$
$$u = g \quad \text{on}\,\,R^n \times \{t = 0\}.$$
The book says that
$$u(x, t) = g(x - tb) \quad x \in R^n, t \geq 0$$
is a solution if $g$ is $C^1$.
Can we ignore the continuity of $g'$ in the proof that it is indeed a solution?
If not, what role does the continuity of $g'$ play in the proof?

If you want to have a classical solution to the stated transport problem, then you should be able to differentiate the solution u w.r.t. $t$ and $x.$ As the solution is given by $u(x,t) = g(x-tb),$ we must be able to write $u_t(x,t) = g'(x-tb)\cdot(-b)$ and $u_x(x,t) = g'(x-tb)\cdot1.$

The answer to your question is yes, provided that we have a reasonable definition of what a discontinuous solution to a PDE means. For classical solutions, differentiability and hence continuity are required for the terms in the PDE to be defined.
